# Angular2 - How to set `touched` property on form to true

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in my component and I want to set the `touched` property on every one of the inputs equal to `true`.  My current code does this, but it throws the error `Cannot set property touched of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter`:

```
addressForm: FormGroup;

...

this.addressForm = this._fb.group({
    street: ["", [<any>Validators.required]],
    city: ["", [<any>Validators.required]],
    state: ["", [<any>Validators.required]],
    zipCode: ["", [<any>Validators.required]],
    country: ["", [<any>Validators.required]]
});

...

for (var key in this.addressForm.controls) {
    this.addressForm.controls[key].touched = true;
}
```

How can I set the `touched` value of every input to `true`?

Comment: **Touched and Untouched** are read only properties.you cannot assign a value.

Comment: BTW if you use #myForm="ngForm" on your HTML form element, you have access to myForm.submitted in the HTML, so might not need to bother with .touched

Comment: @RonNewcomb you should add this as an answer. It save me some effort

Comment: **this.addressForm.controls[key]**.markAsTouched()

Comment: form.control.markAllAsTouched()

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There's a pretty straightforward method to do this: `markAsTouched`. It should be enough to use it on the form group.

```
this.addressForm.markAsTouched()
```

In case you want for some reason to mark all controls manually, they itself have this method available.

`markAsTouched` is a method of the `AbstractControl` all form elements inherit from. Out of curiosity, you might want to visit the `@angular/forms/src/model.d.ts` declaration file to find some more interesting methods of the form objects. Or just visit the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html).

Comment: this.addressForm.form.markAsTouched()

Comment: this.addressForm.controls['controlName'].markAsTouched();

Answer (score 0):

If you use `#myForm="ngForm"` on your HTML form element, you have access to `myForm.submitted` in the HTML, so might not need to bother with `.touched`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component()
export class AppComponent {
  public loginForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.loginForm.markAllAsTouched();
    if(this.loginForm.valid) { ... }
  }
}
```

or better way write once and use it everywhere as a directive :D

```
 import { Directive, Self, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
  import { ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

  @Directive({
    selector: 'form[formGroup]'
  })
  export class MarkAllTouchedDirective {
    @HostListener('submit')
    public onSubmit(): void {
      this.container.control.markAllAsTouched();
    }

    constructor(
      @Self() private container: ControlContainer
    ) {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public markAllAsTouched(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    (Object as any).values(formGroup.controls).forEach((control: any) => {
        control.markAsTouched();
        if (control.controls) {
            this.markAllAsTouched(control);
        }
    });
}
```

Use above function on submit action.

This can be another possible solution.
Reference : https://www.geekstrick.com/markallastouched-in-angular-forms/