# Angular Material 2 md-select required not working on form submit

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I create a simple form with a textbox and a dropdown. Both are required.

When I click submit button textbox becomes red while dropdown doesn't change.

Here the plunkr: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/oSe3JCMlB4jBNsjOgUoc/

I want both fields becames red when user click the submit button.

What I miss?

Comment: Do you want it to show the dropdown as red or neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because the `required` Validator checks to see if the `FormControl` is `touched`.

You can do this manually as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399462/angular2-how-to-set-touched-property-on-from-to-true)

```js
submit(form) {
    this.form.get('test2').markAsTouched()
    console.log(form)
}
```

It is also better to use `(ngSubmit)` instead of a click event on the submit button.

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lkdFq3QOz7dvUHqInWa1?p=preview)

Comment: Yes it works! But textbox validation works even if I don't touch it. Isn't it a bug?

Comment: I honestly don't know - I've searched about a bit but can't find anything about it. Perhaps someone else can shed some light and I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
'test1': new FormControl("", Validators.required)
```

in your code (select-form-example.ts) which is telling angular that it is a required field, hence the red box for failed validation. Try

```
'test1': new FormControl("")
```

Comment: I think he's asking the opposite of this :) hopefully he clarifies!

Comment: I want both fields becames red when user click the submit button!

Comment: The title says "md-select required not working on form submit"... md-select is required but it won't work. I updated the question, I hope is clear now.

Comment: Fair enough! I removed the comment.